# jquery ui dialog not showing in center of window after setting position to center

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm new to jquery ui dialog box. I used dialog box in my MVC website.

I placed my dialog container in layout page inside body tag as follows-

```
 <div id="dialogBox"></div>
```

And then on my view page, I have button with id **aMyProfile** and written jquery code for opening my dialog box.

**html code for aMyProfile -**

```
<input type="button" id="aMyProfile" data-url="@Url.Action("UserProfileContainer","User")" value="View Profile"/>
```

**Jquery code for aMyProfile-**

```
$('#aMyProfile').click(function () {
            var currentURL = $(this).attr('data-url');
            $('#dialogBox').load(currentURL, function () {
                $('#dialogBox').dialog("open");
            });
        });
```

and dialog box initaialization as-

```
$('#dialogBox').dialog({
        bgiframe: true,
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        closeOnEscape: false,
        position: 'center',
        resizable: false,
        title: 'Profile',
        width: 750
    });
```

all above jquery code is inside  **$(document).ready(function () {});**

when i execute my project it is giving me output as -
[image]

My dialog box is not coming at center of window. Even though i set position to center.

I don't understand that where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You're specifying the position value wrong. It should be like this:

```
position: { my: "center", at: "center", of: window }
```

In any case, the default value for position is center aligned, so just remove it.

http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position

Comment: What's the height of your content? Looking at the screen shot, there doesn't seem to be much on the page. If you haven't got any content pushing the height of the body, I'm not sure it will align.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the very same issue. Things to check:

Make sure you have /Scripts/jquery.ui.position.js  in your application, if not go here

http://jqueryui.com/download/ and download it, you'll find it in

\jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom\jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom\development-bundle\ui\jquery.ui.position.js

in App_Start/BundleConfig.cs  change your jqueryui bundle config from this:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"                     
                    ));
```

to this:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.ui.position.js"
                    ));
```

That should sort it.